# Using json_decode on cURL result

Tags: php, curl, openssl

I have got the following code that retrieves data about a company.

```
function getSSLPage($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }


$get_page = getSSLPage('link');
print_r($get_page);
```

The problem is that I cannot retrieve json result. curl_exec() indeed prints the outcome but if I use print_r() or var_dump() on $result, I get int(1) as result.

I tried different variations but everything failed.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and may simplify the code to:

```
function getSSLPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // add other options you need, eg: timeout, etc

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false) {
        //error occurs, use curl_errno/curl_error to get the error
    } else {
        $result = json_decode($result, true);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option.

Answer (score 0):

inside your function

add code below right after `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

```
// Will return the response, if false it prints the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```